# Optimizing Efficiency in a Stack

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, stack

I'm solving a problem on HackerRank where I'm required to implement a simple stack.

[image]

It's passing all the tests except for the last 4 where it fails due to surpassing the time constraint of 10s.  These 4 failing tests are running 200,000 operations on the stack.

How can I optimize my code below:

```
# operations of the form ['push -36', 'pop', 'push 16', 'pop', 'inc 1 -17', ...]

from collections import deque

def superStack(operations):

    def push(v):
        S.append(int(v))

    def pop():
        return S.pop()

    def inc(i,v):
        i, v = int(i), int(v)
        for pos in range(i):
            S[pos] += v

    S = deque()
    funcs = locals()

    for operation in operations:
        op, *args = operation.split(' ')
        funcs[op](*args)

        print(S[-1] if S else "EMPTY")
```

---

A few notes:

- Some constraints:

  [image]
- I've chosen `deque` over `list`, to avoid the "contiguous memory block" problem that lists  may encounter.
- Since `pop` and `append` are both O(1), the heaviest operation is the `inc` (especially so if `i` is large). So I keep all items as integers to avoid conversion from string to int multiple times in the `inc` loop

Comment: Please link to the problem so we can try it ourselves.

Comment: @superbrain Unfortunately, I can't do that, I think it was part of a private test suite. And I no longer have access.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just be lazy. Don't do what you're told. They'll never know.

Instead of truly increasing the bottom `i` values right away, just make a note at the `i`-th value from the bottom to increase it by `v` when it gets popped. And when that pop happens, move the note to the value below, so it gets increased by `v` as well (when it gets popped). And so on, so that this will add `v` to *all* bottom `i` values (when they get popped).

To support multiple `inc` operations: If a value already has a note to add `w` to it (and all values below it), change that to `w + v`.

For easier coding, just store *all* values along with such a note, but with initial adding value `0`.

Now all three operations are O(1).

Oh wait. Not quite O(1), since you're using a deque so you can't access an arbitrary index in O(1). That's actually a problem in your solution as well. Your increasing the bottom `i` values isn't O(i) but only O(i<sup>2</sup>). If you switch to a list, yours would be O(i) and mine would be O(1). This loses the O(1) of appending/popping to/from a deque, but the list still does them in *amortized* O(1). So then all three operations are amortized O(1). Alternatively you could keep your deque and store the notes in a separate *dict*, but then it's O(1) just as much as dict access is O(1) (i.e., not truly, but practically), and I suspect it would be a bit slower than the list version.

Comment: How do you handle the case with multiple inc operations where the i value is lesser than previous inc operations. 
For example: 

`['push 1', 'push 2', 'push 3', 'inc 3 5', 'inc 1 5']`

So the bottom-most element is now incremented by 10, while the top two are incremented by 5.

Comment: As described in the answer. There's nothing special about that.

Comment: +1, makes sense to me now, good solution!